# SQL: How can i find the records of a dataset that exist in a datetime range of 30 minutes for a column 'Created_at'?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT t1.depar_date, t1.return_date, t1.orig_air, t1.dest_air, t1.num_pass, count(t1.id) as count_of, 'TRUE' as Hit_Cache
FROM MY_TEST t1
WHERE  t1.created_at BETWEEN t1.created_at AND dateadd(minute, 30, t1.created_at) --t1.created_at > dateadd(DAY, 1, t1.created_at)
GROUP BY t1.depar_date, t1.return_date, t1.orig_air, t1.dest_air, t1.num_pass
HAVING count(t1.id) > 1;
```

The `DATEADD` does not be recognized and throws me error.

Comment: What error you have got? What is the type of `created_at`?

Comment: And also what's the database engine sql server or mysql?

Comment: This clause in your query will always come back **true** on SQL Server : `t1.created_at BETWEEN t1.created_at AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, t1.created_at)`  On MySQL it will throw an error.  Please [edit] your question to explain a little more fully what you want to do. And, please delete either the [mysql] or [sql-server] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalize MINUTE or use mm in lower case:

```
SELECT t1.depar_date, t1.return_date, t1.orig_air, t1.dest_air,        t1.num_pass, count(t1.id) as count_of, 'TRUE' as Hit_Cache
FROM MY_TEST t1
WHERE  t1.created_at BETWEEN t1.created_at AND dateadd(MINUTE, 30,     t1.created_at) --t1.created_at > dateadd(DAY, 1, t1.created_at)
GROUP BY t1.depar_date, t1.return_date, t1.orig_air, t1.dest_air, t1.num_pass
HAVING count(t1.id) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your query gacked on `DATEADD()` I guess you are working with MySQL.

It looks to me like you want to know how many *other* records in your table lie within a half-hour of each record.

Because you want to compare records to records, you need a self-join operation.  Specifically, you want something like this

```
   FROM MY_TEST t1
   JOIN MY_TEST t2 ON something.
```

This construct makes it look like you're querying two different tables `t1` and `t2`, even though they're the same data.

I think your comparison will look like this

```
  FROM MY_TEST t1
  JOIN MY_TEST t2 
       ON t2.created_at BETWEEN t1.created_at AND t1.created_at + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

The result of this join operation consists of all possible combinations of pairs of rows in the table that match the `ON` condition.  You then proceed to select and summarize from that bunch of pairs of rows.

The rest of your query looks very similar to what you have in your question.

```
SELECT t1.depar_date, t1.return_date, t1.orig_air, 
       t1.dest_air, t1.num_pass, count(t1.id) as count_of,
       'TRUE' as Hit_Cache
  FROM MY_TEST t1
  JOIN MY_TEST t2 
       ON t2.created_at BETWEEN t1.created_at AND t1.created_at + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
 GROUP BY t1.depar_date, t1.return_date, t1.orig_air, t1.dest_air, t1.num_pass
HAVING count(t1.id) > 1;
```

Maybe I guessed wrong about MySQL. In SQL Server your ON clause will look like this.

```
       ON t2.created_at BETWEEN t1.created_at AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, t1.created_at)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood that you said and you are right, but i have still problem with the DATEADD function. The MINUTE argument is not recognized.